# Modifying Zipcode Search In Templatic GeoPlaces Theme

Tags: wordpress, geolocation, themes

I'm working on setting up a site with the Geo Places theme from Templatic... The only issue is that the 'Near' search only matches exact Zip codes and not nearby or city, etc. (Theme http://templatic.com/cms-themes/geo-places-city-directory-wordpress-theme)

Am I crazy or is there a way to make this work or at least tweak the zipcode search to include a few zipcodes higher and lower than the one entered. For example, if they enter '90210' it returns a range 10 codes around that, (90205 through 90215) or something similar.

I'm open to suggestions. Even alternate themes or even Drupal or Joomla options.

Thanks for the help-

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.geomywp.com this plugin works with any post type and let you search by any address and radius.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. I fixed with relevanssi plugin. You have to carefully set up the options. In this way the Geo Places will find for relevance by ZIP Code or City Name. I cannot give link to my page because still working on and is offline.